# Problem with Settings entity. CloudKit subscription adds the same subscription twice and miss the other one from the list

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

I simply register subscription for my iCloud entities the following way:

```
    let options: CKQuerySubscriptionOptions = [.firesOnRecordCreation, .firesOnRecordUpdate, .firesOnRecordDeletion]
    let territoryGroupSubscription = CKQuerySubscription(recordType: "TerritoryGroup", predicate: NSPredicate(value: true), options: options)
    let serviceSubscription = CKQuerySubscription(recordType: "Service", predicate: NSPredicate(value: true), options: options)
    let goalSubscription = CKQuerySubscription(recordType: "Goal", predicate: NSPredicate(value: true), options: options)
    let territorySubscription = CKQuerySubscription(recordType: "Territory", predicate: NSPredicate(value: true), options: options)
    let addressSubscription = CKQuerySubscription(recordType: "Address", predicate: NSPredicate(value: true), options: options)
    let noteSubscription = CKQuerySubscription(recordType: "Note", predicate: NSPredicate(value: true), options: options)
    let daySubscription = CKQuerySubscription(recordType: "Day", predicate: NSPredicate(value: true), options: options)
    let categorySubscription = CKQuerySubscription(recordType: "Category", predicate: NSPredicate(value: true), options: options)
    let shareSubscription = CKQuerySubscription(recordType: "cloudkit.share", predicate: NSPredicate(value: true), options: options)
    let settingsSubscription = CKQuerySubscription(recordType: "Settings", predicate: NSPredicate(value: true), options: options)
    let notificationInfo = CKNotificationInfo()
    notificationInfo.shouldBadge = false
    notificationInfo.shouldSendContentAvailable = true
    
    territoryGroupSubscription.notificationInfo = notificationInfo
    serviceSubscription.notificationInfo = notificationInfo
    goalSubscription.notificationInfo = notificationInfo
    territorySubscription.notificationInfo = notificationInfo
    addressSubscription.notificationInfo = notificationInfo
    noteSubscription.notificationInfo = notificationInfo
    daySubscription.notificationInfo = notificationInfo
    categorySubscription.notificationInfo = notificationInfo
    shareSubscription.notificationInfo = notificationInfo
    settingsSubscription.notificationInfo = notificationInfo

    let privateSubscriptionsOperation = CKModifySubscriptionsOperation(subscriptionsToSave: [settingsSubscription, territoryGroupSubscription, serviceSubscription, goalSubscription, territorySubscription, addressSubscription, noteSubscription, daySubscription, categorySubscription, shareSubscription], subscriptionIDsToDelete: nil)
    privateSubscriptionsOperation.database = CloudAssistant.shared.privateDatabase
    
    let queue = OperationQueue()
    queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1
    queue.addOperation(privateSubscriptionsOperation)
```

And this is the output for my operation in cloudkit dashboard:

[image]
[image]

As you can see there is 10 subscriptions (as expected) but two of them are duplicated for `Category` Record Type (3th and 6th row). And of course `Settings` Record Type is missing. Why? Where should I look for the problem?

**UPDATE:**

When I remove all subscriptions from icloud dashboard, then only 9 is subscribed, without `Settings`. Why there is issue with Settings?

Is it reserved name for system entities or what?

Comment: 1) Do you actually have a Settings record type in your private database? 2) Have you looked at the console logs when your subscription code is being run? Any messages about the Settings subscription?

Comment: 1. Yes, I have. It is defined in cloudki dashboard and in my core data model also. 2. There is no error at all. No messages...

Comment: @HangarRash The interesting thing is that when I fetch changes manually... changes for Settings of course are fetched as well as the other entities. But notification about the change doesnt arrive. And it happen ONLY for Settings entity. I doesnt arrive because there is no subscription for it. But why the code doesnt add it? I do it in my code.

Comment: Just as a sanity check, delete all subscriptions and comment out your code such that you only attempt to create the Settings subscription. Does it work now or not?

Comment: Looks like a bug. What happens if the Setting subscription is not the last one in your code?

Comment: @HangarRash I tried to register ONLY Settings after I removed all subscriptions... and nothing has been subscribed. After all I have registered one more time all entities, and everything was subscribed except Settings‍♂️ It is a bug, I think...

Comment: @ReinhardMänner doesnt matter, event it is the ONLY ONE Subscription in my code it doesnt work...

Comment: Try renaming your Settings record type. Maybe there's something special about the name "Settings". That's the last idea I have on this.

Comment: @HangarRash it is not just "rename it". It brings a lot of difficult consequences... I simply cannot;)

Comment: OK, I just thought of one more idea. Use the `perSubscriptionSaveBlock` property of `CKModifySubscriptionsOperation` and see what you get for the Settings record type.